# how to group together related fields in form submission

Tags: html, forms

I'm building a complex form, and the form happen to edit "Group", and i have a bunch of subgroup for each group, i would also like to provide a simple way for people to edit the subgroups within this edit page. How would i group the fields together in subgroup edit box so that when submitting the form, it will be grouped together somehow to distinguish the fact that a certain "set" of fields belong into one unit?

Note that there is no limit to how many subgroup it can have. I would like it so that each unit of inputs will be grouped together for easy consumption in the back.

A problem with my current approach is that even though i can just loop through each of group_name, group_descrp array and match it up that way (by index), the checkbox ruins it by not showing up if it is unchecked, and the value of checked checkbox is just on, and i have no way of passing in the information group_id.

Example:

```
<form>
<!-- group 1 -->
<input name="group_name[]">
<input name="group_descrp[]">
<input type="hidden" name="group_id[]">
<input type="checkbox" name="group_del[]">

<!-- group2 -->
<input name="group_name[]">
<input name="group_descrp[]">
<input type="hidden" name="group_id[]">
<input type="checkbox" name="group_del[]">
...
</form>
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

How about a common class name?  jQuery and many of its plugins are all about class-based selectors, so why not?

Comment: i'm not trying to select using jquery, i'm trying to submit the form to the server for processing

Comment: Sooo.. what server-side technology are you using?

Comment: Spring MVC (Java) on the server side, but if you have some idea how to do it in PHP it would be greatly appreciated as well :)